# List of list in Jinja2

Tags: list, dictionary, jinja2

I want to loop over lists using a list containing the lists name, eg :

```
{% set album = ['one','two'] %}
{% set one = ['a','b','c'] %}
{% set two = ['d','e','f'] %}
{% for alb in album %}
{% for songs in alb %}
{{ songs }}
{%- endfor %}
{%- endfor %}
```

but it doesn't work...how can I achieve something like that ? (I want to split the lists because they are long) 
Thank's

Answer (score 0):

Create album from previously set lists `one` and `two` and it will work

```
{% set one = ['a','b','c'] %}
{% set two = ['d','e','f'] %}
{% set album = [one, two] %}
{% for alb in album %}
    {% for songs in alb %}
        {{ songs }}
    {%- endfor %}
{%- endfor %}
```